# Using REGEXP to change spaces into hyphens in limited situations

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a keywords column and it contains stuff like this:

> apples, oranges, pine apple

I'm trying to change the spaces to hyphens using this query"

```
UPDATE articles SET keywords = REPLACE(keywords," ","-") WHERE
keywords REGEXP '[A-Z] [A-Z]' limit 1;
```

But this adds hyphens where I don't want them, like this:

> apples,-oranges,-pine-apple

Can this be done with REGEXP? Or will I need to involve PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: Obviously, this `[A-Z] [A-Z]` is not getting matched. So, it ends up replacint all spaces with - no matter where they are. Why, I don't know. Could be the limit 1 ? Or, maybe the regex is not properly delimited / stringified / funcified

Comment: Where do you want the space, between pine and apple? The regex just confirms the column matches, the replace functions works on the whole column.

Comment: Instead of apples,-oranges,-pine-apple I want apples, oranges, pine-apple

Comment: Try to use something like this: UPDATE articles SET keywords = REPLACE(TRIM(keywords)," ","-") WHERE
keywords REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+' limit 1;

Comment: If the provided answer was helpful, please vote it up. If it answered your question, please mark it accepted so this question can be closed off. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting rows based on the regular expression, but how does `REPLACE()` know about that? It's going to replace spaces with hyphens, just like you told it.

There are a few options for adding regexp-based search and replace in MySQL such as a [UDF](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp), and [MariaDB supports it natively](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_replace/):

```
UPDATE articles SET keywords = REGEXP_REPLACE(keywords, "[A-Z] [A-Z]", "-");
```

Also worth mentioning that a `LIMIT` clause without an `ORDER BY` clause is not very helpful.